# Block-diagonal forms and SVD(singular value decomposition)

Tags: linear-algebra, svd, block-matrices

I have a matrix X that is in a block-diagonal-form of two $n \times n$ matrices A
\begin{bmatrix}
A & 0 \\
0 & A \\
\end{bmatrix}
My goal is to extract A from X, so I thought it would be a good idea to perform SVD in the following manner,
$X = USV^{\dagger}= \sum_{i={odd}} s_{i} U_{i}V^{\dagger}_{i}+\sum_{i={even}} s_{i} U_{i}V^{\dagger}_{i}$ , and each terms should corresponds to A, as all the singular values should be paired. I have testified  this numerically using  the following python codes.

```
A = np.random.randn(n,n) 
X = np.kron(np.eye(2),A)
U,s,V = np.linalg.svd(X,full_matrices=False)

A1=0
A2=0

for i in range(0,len(s),2):
    A1 += s[i]*np.outer(U[:,i],V[i,:])
for i in range(1,len(s),2):
    A2 += s[i]*np.outer(U[:,i],V[i,:])
X_test =A1+ A2
```

I have observed that when n is small we can extract A from X exactly, but if n is large enough the "A1 or A2" in the code no longer equals to A. Why did this happens?

P.S I plotted the Frobenius norm of $|A-A_{1}|_{fro}$ against the dimension of A below. I hope this helps.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgA92.png)

Comment: The spectrum of $X^TX$ necessarily has repeated eigenvalues hence your eigenvectors (singular vectors of $X$) live in subspaces with dimension $\geq 2$

Comment: @tokyo I would recommend checking if the answer becomes exact when you remove the `full_matrices=False` specification.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you for your comment. I have check "full_matrices=False specification", but did not change the result. Instead, I have attached a supplemental figure of Frobenius norms of $|−1|$ vs. the dimension of the matrix.